# uploaded image exceeding the maximum file size of <em class="placeholder">

Tags: 8

I am using Drupal 8.3.5 and Lightning 8.x-2.16. When I upload an image in an image field that exceeds the max file size. I get the page warning: `The file is <em class="placeholder">826.11 KB</em> exceeding the maximum file size of <em class="placeholder">25 KB</em>`. I would like to remove the placeholder text
    `<em class="placeholder"></em>` To reproduce this I installed a fresh Drupal Lightning site. Added a plain image field to the Page content type and set Maximum upload size to 80 KB. Then try to upload an image that is over that file size.